# Pdf File mysteriously deleted!

Tags: compiling

While compiling my LaTeX document on TeXmaker, I kept on getting an error message. I realized that this was a result of the fact that I had the pdf file open simultaneously. However, when I closed the pdf file, and try to re-compile the document, I received a very strange error message that says 
`! File ended while scanning use of \@footnotetext.`
In fact, the pdf file does not exist anymore, and it is not in the recycle bin either. Why can it not produce a new pdf file? Thanks!

Comment: Removing an *.aux file should help.

Comment: This is because you've obviously made changes since you created the pdf. Now, on compilation, an error has been hit, apparently quite early on, and LaTeX has encountered that error before it's produced a page of pdf so it hasn't created the new pdf, because there's an error in your code. You need to fix that error and then when you compile it will create the working pdf (assuming there are no other errors)

Comment: you have an error in a footnote so no pdf got made, most likely a missing `}` but hard to guess given no information

Comment: The error I see now is "Error : could not start the command : "C:/Program Files/Ghostgum/gsview/gsview32.exe" "Literature Review".ps
"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an error in a footnote so no pdf got made, most likely a missing `}` .